# how to retrieve image column from sharepoint list using sp-pnp-js in SPFX webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, boot-strap

I am not able retrieve image column from SharePoint list in my solution using `sp-pnp-js`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code inside **forEach**:

```
let imageUrl = item.Picture.Url
```

**OR**

```
let imageUrl = item["Picture"].Url
```

Then pass this image URL inside `src` attribute of `img` tag.

Comment: how to retrieve date column fields from sharepoint list

Comment: Are you able to retrieve and use image URL using above code? You can get date column using `let dateColValue = item.InternalNameOfDateCol` **OR** `let dateColValue = item["InternalNameOfDateCol"]`. make sure you are using correct [internal names](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could get picture url this way:

```
item.pictureColumnName.Url
```

get date column:

```
item.dateColumnName
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
JSON.parse(item.ImageColumName).serverRelativeUrl
```

BUT I was using CAML query to retrieve items.